# Self-contained password manager with CLI

Tags: password, software-rec

I'm looking for a password manager that has the following properties:

1. The manager is entirely self-contained. I take and install a directory on a thumbdrive and execute from that drive. It should also be self-contained.
2. The database should easily identifiable and moveable by hand. So for example,I could copy it to another thumbdrive, without copying the executable.
3. There should a commandline interface. A gui is fine and probably better then a curses based one, but I also want the ability to type on the commandline:

> *retrieve_password*  for_this_app_or_site for_this_user.
>
> There should be at least a manager on Android which uses the same database.
>   A Windows version whould be a plus too but not mandatory.

Comment: There is a [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site, which would probably be a much better place for this. Especially since you want Windows and Android versions (both of which are outside our scope). Please review their [guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) before asking over there, though.

Answer (score 4):

[pass](http://www.passwordstore.org/) is a tool to store passwords in gpg-encrypted single files that can be grouped in folders. The code is written in shell code and follows the Unix philosophy. `pass` does not have an Android GUI interface but the password files themshelfs could be read using a GPG manager.